# GeoServer publish layer using REST API with custom band name under Coverage Band Detail

Tags: geoserver-rest-api, coverage

I'm trying to publish a existing coverage storage using custom Band name, the information is available from GeoServer GUI here:
[image: geoserver GUI screen capture]

How do I publish this store through Geoserver REST API with a custom name? For example, I might want this name to be "Elevation" instead of "GRAY_INDEX"

Currently, I'm able to get the store published using defaults from below request XML body.

```
<coverage>
  <name>LAYER_NAME</name>
  <title>TITLE_NAME</title>
  <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
</coverage>
```

Comment: Did you try making the change in the GUI and asking for the XML via rest?

Comment: Hi @IanTurton I see the option of making change to the band name in the GUI, just wondering how to perform the same action using REST

Comment: You can make the change in the GUI, then request the XML with GET and inspect it to see what needs to be there